# Zabuto Calendar with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, calendar

How can I get the events stored in my db to show in the calendar ?
I can't seem to figure out how to replace the random dates with my own ones :/

Basically I have to loop through the data i get from my db don't I ?
And put the data in the JSON format ...

Can I use a foreach loop ?

this is the code provided by the zabuto calendar download site

```
<?php include_once 'includes/sessions.php'; ?>
<?php include_once 'includes/connect.php';
/**
 * Example of JSON data for calendar
*
* @package zabuto_calendar
*/


if (!empty($_REQUEST['year']) && !empty($_REQUEST['month'])) {
$year = intval($_REQUEST['year']);
$month = intval($_REQUEST['month']);
$lastday = intval(strftime('%d', mktime(0, 0, 0, ($month == 12 ? 1 : $month + 1), 0, ($month == 12 ? $year + 1 : $year))));


$dates = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= (rand(4, 10)); $i++) {
    $date = $year . '-' . str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '-' . str_pad(rand(1, $lastday), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$dates[$i] = array(
        'date' => $date,
        'badge' => ($i & 1) ? true : false,
        'title' => 'Example for ' . $date,
        'body' => '<p class="lead">Information for this date</p><p>You can add <strong>html</strong> in this block</p>',
        'footer' => 'Extra information',
    );

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['grade'])) {
        $dates[$i]['badge'] = false;
        $dates[$i]['classname'] = 'grade-' . rand(1, 4);
    }

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['action'])) {
        $dates[$i]['title'] = 'Action for ' . $date;
        $dates[$i]['body'] = '<p>The footer of this modal window consists of two buttons. One button to close the modal window without further action.</p>';
        $dates[$i]['body'] .= '<p>The other button [Go ahead!] fires myFunction(). The content for the footer was obtained with the AJAX request.</p>';
        $dates[$i]['body'] .= '<p>The ID needed for the function can be retrieved with jQuery: <code>dateId = $(this).closest(\'.modal\').attr(\'dateId\');</code></p>';
        $dates[$i]['body'] .= '<p>The second argument is true in this case, so the function can handle closing the modal window: <code>myFunction(dateId, true);</code></p>';
        $dates[$i]['footer'] = '
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="dateId = $(this).closest(\'.modal\').attr(\'dateId\'); myDateFunction(dateId, true);">Go ahead!</button>
        ';
    }
}

echo json_encode($dates);

} else {
echo json_encode(array());
}
```

Comment: yes, you can definitely use a for loop (i just did this today).  have you looked at the json you return?  try looking at it in chrome or firefox debugger network response and send a screenshot or add the json you see...